# When should we overturn an owner's decision to delete their question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

Thumbing through recent undelete votes, I noticed a few cases like this:

[image]

Where the user asking a question voluntarily deleted it, and a few people have voted to undelete the question.

We are, of course, legally allowed to undelete it. The user irrevocably licensed the content to us. That's a given.

But *should* we? At what point do we overturn an author's decision to retract their question? What if there are good answers on the question already?

Comment: certainly a case by case situation. If it's a question that will be useful to a group of people if answered, why not?

Comment: Also on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106619/what-are-valid-reasons-to-vote-to-undelete-posts-deleted-by-their-owners

Comment: The author may have many reasons for deleting the question, and it may not be obvious why. A good reason may be to disassociate themselves with the question or context surrounding it, and by reinstating it as-is you are denying them the anonymity they seek. If the question is deemed useful enough to consider reinstating it, then perhaps it could be reinstated as a community wiki, or references to the original author removed?

Comment: I'm thinking that with over 10,000,000 answers, the op should be in charge.  It's not like SO is hurting for answers.  Give the Op latitude and they'll be back for more, bully them and they won't.

Comment: Isn't part of the goal of SO to aim for high quality? Efforts of so many people are put into this task. So, if an OP chooses to delete a question, it may well be because it's a bad question. Let's trust the OPs to know this, like we trust so many to edit/close/etc.

Comment: @Tro: Without license from the author, SE is barred from disassociating his work. And making it CW would be a very invasive change with huge downsides. For example, if it's a question all answers also become CW.

Comment: You should never do this.

Comment: @Tro Note that you **can** ask to be disassociated from a question, so deleting to achieve that effect is simply *wrong*.

Comment: Is your user name a coincidence @Undo? This question is lacking an answer from a user _redo_ and some intervention from _abort♦_. Some comments from _cancel_ might end up being deleted by _OK♦_. User names being related to the topic at hand is quite meta, even for meta.

Answer (score 33):

It's very much a case-by-case decision.

In this case, from what little context we have, it appears that the question said something wasn't working which, in fact, *was* working — e.g., observation error. In that case, the question is useless and should remain deleted.

But if someone asks a question that belongs on the site (isn't a complete duplicate, is on-topic, etc.), gets an answer (a real answer, or a comment), then deletes it before the answer gets upvoted (at which point they can't), well then that's just abusing the system (probably unintentionally). If the question belongs on the site, it should remain on the site. Questions and answers are primarily intended for reference by future readers, not just to help the OP who posted the question originally.

OP embarrassment isn't a factor to consider. If an OP has a question they're embarrassed to have asked and that question is never deleted (got an upvoted answer in time) or is undeleted, the OP can ask via a custom flag to be disassociated from the question.

Comment: Why not automatically disassociate the user rather than delete. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @SystemicPlural: I doubt it's really necessary, I don't think most OPs really care and in many cases, the deletion may well have been a misguided attempt to "clean up" after themselves because they don't quite get the SO model (yet). So the principal of least complexity (just undelete the question) applies. But if you disagree, you could post a feature request asking for it.

Comment: Rather than that, though, I'd prefer to see a mechanism for simply disassociating yourself from the question directly rather than having to ask someone to do it for you. Any potential abuse could be handled via monitoring, and disassociating yourself from rubbish questions would need to not prevent the various automated mechanisms that help avoid people (primarily newbies) from repeatedly posting bad questions. (Although I worry about the Law of Unintended Consequences -- e.g., what am I missing in that, which could be exploited... :-) )

Comment: disassociate the op and just show it as anonymous without the link.

Comment: @BipinKareparambil: I believe that's what SstemicPlural said above.

Comment: @TJCrowder Yes an extra option could work. Perhaps when delete is clicked the option can be presented.

Comment: If the OP does delete a question which had one or more answers people had put time into, flag for moderator attention to get the question undeleted. Sometimes it is unthinking by OP, sometimes, for instance, to hide that they got their coursework done for them.

Comment: If someone posts a question that isn't a complete duplicate, is on-topic, and can be reasonably answered, and you have a reasonable answer (in a comment, or in an answer).... you really should bump their question up to +1: the question is already better than half of the questions asked here!  If you didn't, was it worth saving?

Comment: @Yakk: The OP can delete their question if it's upvoted. What they can't do is delete it if it has an upvoted answer. (And yes, indeed, a question meeting the criteria should indeed be upvoted.)

Comment: @SystemicPlural: Maybe because the author never gave license to disassociate him?

Answer (score 10):

One situation that I was in was that I spent considerable time answering a [question with a 200 point bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16373996/712765) that the author awarded, but then later he deleted the question, taking back the 200 points. Fortunately [after I complained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180140/retain-bounty-awarded-even-if-question-is-deleted), the community undeleted the question for me, for which I was very grateful.

So in this case a question was asked, answered, and bounty awarded before the author decided to delete the question. I felt deleting the question and taking back the bounty was unfair to me, and enough community members agreed that it was undeleted over the author's objection. (Plus, of course, the question was useful and on-topic, and the answer helpful to other people with the same or similar problem.)

Comment: A question should stand on it's own regardless of how many points were awarded. The fact that deleting a question would have an effect on anyone's reputation points should never be a factor.

Comment: It would be a loophole if deleting a question was “taking back the bounty”. The [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) clearly says: “*All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances*”. So a user may be able to abandon a bounty by deleting the question but it shouldn’t take it back, i.e. the associated rep points are lost forever then. Otherwise, it’s a bug.

Comment: @Holger If you [read my original complaint/feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180140/retain-bounty-awarded-even-if-question-is-deleted) you will see that I agree with you that deleting the question should not take back the bounty, but it is _policy_ (not a bug) that bounties are taken back when questions are deleted. (That is, they are taken back from the person to whom they were awarded; they are not given back to the person who offered the bounty.) Feel free to upvote my feature request if you want that changed.

Answer (score 2):

In situations where the OP has asked a question that is off-topic, I don't see a benefit in having the question restored since it would just end up getting closed.  In this particular instance the off-topic reason would be that the problem is "not reproducible":

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

If the question has no answers and is closed (for a reason other than "duplicate"), it will likely be deleted at a later point by the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) anyway.